# Unable to create a .html file with run time values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have below code which have to create html file with run time values.

```
var fs = require('fs');

 const html = generateHtml(content); //Its successfully generated html content

 fs.writeFileSysnc(buildPathHtml, html,(err) => {
                  if(err)
                  {
                    throw err;
                    console.log(err)
                  }
                });
                log.info('Succesfully created an HTML Report at ' + buildPathHtml);
```

I set the debug mode and I can see the entire .html structure that stored in html const in the above code and buildPathHtml is the location of the file.

But when I run the code and the below error is observed in output console. And the content is failed to write.

**Output Console:**

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\arrchanaMohan\testCode\IncentRacktor\Test\shark\Reports\SANITY_2020-06-26:08:32:56.html'
```

**Build Path:**
c:\Users\arrchanaMohan\testCode\IncentRacktor\Test\shark\Reports\SANITY_2020-06-26:08:32:56.html

Appending the timestamp after 'SANITY_'

Comment: Aren't colons forbidden characters in a file name?

Comment: How does the buildPath look like?

Comment: `writeFileSync` Doesn't use a callback,.. the 3rd parameter is options. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options

Comment: I just append the timestamp in the report.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to @Teemu

I just removed colon (:) and used _ in the build path. And It worked.

Comment: Sorry.. I should tell to you.. I think you are the one who told me about the Colon... !!! The issue got fixed so may be I'm little bit excited. Thanks once again for helping me..